# creating a new row in ListView and then writing to COM port delayed ListView loadtime, solution?

Tags: c#, listview, serial-port

the listview renders the row item quite fast at normal state. but when I call a function to write to a COM port (POLE DISPLAY) . the load time of list view increases and slows down whole process.
I've first called a function to add an item to the listview. The list view uses addrange method to add items.
then  the vfd function is called which will open a COM port first and initialize a port then write to the port.

Here is a full sample code:

```
//function to add new row item in the listview
private void ListFunction(int id)
  {
   ListViewItem checkitem = listView1.FindItemWithText(GetProduct(id));
   if (checkitem != null)
   {
    //MessageBox.Show("It Already Exist");
    int itemvalue = int.Parse(checkitem.SubItems[2].Text) + 1;
    checkitem.SubItems[2].Text = itemvalue.ToString();
                int ttlamt = GetPrice(id) * int.Parse(checkitem.SubItems[2].Text);
                string totalamount = ttlamt.ToString();
                checkitem.SubItems[4].Text = totalamount;
   }
   else
   {
                          // if it doesnot exist
                int ttlamt = GetPrice(id);
    ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("1");
    item1.SubItems.Add(GetProduct(id));
    item1.SubItems.Add("1");
    item1.SubItems.Add(GetPrice(id).ToString());
                string totalamount = ttlamt.ToString();
                item1.SubItems.Add(totalamount);
    listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1 });
   }
       // Write to port
public void VFD(int id)
  {
   SerialPort VFD = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            VFD.Open();
   VFD.Write(initialize);
   VFD.Write(GetProduct(id) + ":" + GetPrice(id));
   VFD.Write("\x1B\x6c\x09\x02");
   VFD.Write("Total: " + totalAmt.Text);
      VFD.Close();


  }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   int id = 10001;
//add to list
   ListFunction(id);


   // VFD Display 
   VFD(id);;
  }
```

All of the items are called from the database.

This slows down the list render performance.

How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

You could send the data to the COM port on a separate thread so this one isn't held up, but be careful to make your code thread-safe.